# Hidden Markov Model with conditional observations

Tags: hidden-markov-model, graphical-model

I am looking for a research paper that basically describes a hidden markov model that has multiple observations, and some observations that have conditional dependencies. For example, please consider the following figure that shows two latent states with 5 observed variables. Here the variable obs5 is dependent on it's parent obs1-obs4. I am aware of HMMs that have single level of observed variables. However, I am not able to find any literature that has the following graphical model structure. So my question is, are there any works/ research papers that model such HMMs?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for a research paper that basically describes a hidden
>   markov model that has multiple observations,...

If there was no `obs5`, it would have been called a [Dynamic Naive Bayes Model](http://www.revistas.unam.mx/index.php/jart/article/view/25279) (DNB).There aren't many software packages/modules that can deal with DNB's, but since the observed variables are indepenedent, you can basically take an open source HMM module or code your own and expand its "[Baum-Welch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baum%E2%80%93Welch_algorithm)" method to calculate the likelihoods of multiple (independent) variables (as opposed to let's say, just `obs1`).

> ...and some observations that have conditional dependencies.

Now, that is black magic territory (!). The general name of the structure you posted is a [Dynamic Bayesian Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Bayesian_network). There aren't many mortals who have achieved to tame that beast.

Joke aside, it is a complicated field and the theoretical solutions that exist can only do so subject to various constraints and I do not know of many DBN packages that you can use out of the box. Especially trying to do structure learning or performing inference on DBN's requires a black-belt in graphical probabilistic models.

Kevin Murphy (who has that black belt) gave [this presentation](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/dbntalk.pdf) on HMMs, DBNs, etc. Maybe good for a quick overview.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Yes, they are indeed dynamic bayesian network. In fact, they are also referred by dynamic template models [Daphne Koller PGM principles and techniques](again a very specific type of dynamic bayes-nets). However, as stated above my only concern is with those dependent observations. I don't require any software packages, I just want to know if there are research papers that target similar PGM structures.